# Prevent Vetur formating

Tags: vue.js, format, vetur

Using Vue.js I some time have a lot of parameters when calling a component in the html like way. And Vetur is completly lost when formating this.

Is there a way to tell Vetur to ignore some lines, in the same way we can do it with eslint ?

Comment: I just switch using Volar instead of Vetur, dunno if it helps in your case but maybe worth a quick try

Comment: especially if you are using Vue 3